# Javascript function onload to block other functions running

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way in JavaScript where I can execute some functions only after page is loaded. Other functions should execute only on an event.

The problem is, I have some calculations in my php page and after doing all the calculations, the data is saved in mysql. Now when I come to the *edit mode* some functions are executing which makes the total field as `NaN`. I just want the code to take the total field from the db only not from any function. Hope l'm clear.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/eb8gaon5/5/)

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/eb8gaon5/5/

Comment: The script is bit lengthy. Now the last field is Margin. Iam taking the totals of the margin field and putting at the bottom called Sub Total.

Comment: i know its difficult to understand the code and suggest me an option. Anyways thanks everyone for your time..:)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this:**

Make an AJAX call to the server to get the count from Database when the user clicks on edit mode and avoid getting from the html document.

```
function JQueryGETAjaxCall(servletPath,callBck){
    var path = window.location.origin
    var url = path+servletPath;
    console.log(url)
    $.ajax({
        'type':'GET',
        'url':url,
        'async': true,
        'success':function(res){
                callBck(res);
        },
        'error':function(res){

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is there any other way. I dont want to make Ajax calls.